# Passing down functions and hooks in React? Or keeping it all together?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to hooks and React. I have the following code:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

let doSomething = (obj, section, setActiveItem, subs, i) => {
  if (
    obj.previousPosition === 'in' &&
    obj.currentPosition === 'below'
  ) {

    if (i !== 0) {
      setActiveItem(subs[i - 1].id);
    }
  }
};

export default ({ data }) => {

  const subs = [
    {
      label: 'Section 1',
      id: 'section1',
      ref: useRef(null),
    },
    {
      label: 'Section 2',
      id: 'section2',
      ref: useRef(null),
    },
  ];

  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState('section1');

  return (
    <>
      {subs.map((sub, i) => {
        return (
          <Waypoint
            key={sub.id}
            bottomOffset="75%"
            onEnter={obj => {
              doSomething(obj, sub.id, setActiveItem, subs, i);
              //I DONT LIKE THAT I NEED TO PASS ON EVERYTHING HERE
            }}
          >
            <Section id={sub.id} ref={sub.ref} />
          </Waypoint>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

Now my problem is that at my `onEnter` function, I need to pass all of these properties to the function `doSomething`, since it needs them. But this doesn't seem right or clean.

- How would I usually handle this with hooks? Can I somehow put it all into one class? But then I would have normal state again, wouldn't I? I am a bit confused about the setup here.

Comment: Do you need `doSomething` to be outside of the component?

Comment: no, not really. but I don't understand how the code would look like with `doSomething` inside the component, using hooks. : /

Answer (score 0):

If you put `doSomething` into your component, you can at least remove two of the five arguments passed to it:

```
const component = ({ data }) => {
    const subs = [];
    const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState('section1');

    const doSomething = (obj, section, i) => {
        /* ... */
        setActiveItem(subs[i - 1].id);
    }

    return (
        { /* ... */ }
        <Waypoint onEnter={(obj) => doSomething(obj, sub.id, i)} { ... } />
        { /* ... */ }
    );
}
```

---

Based on your code you can also remove `sub.id` as you are not currently using it in the function.

But I would recommend to remove `i` from the arguments and use the `section` argument instead of checking if `i !== 0` and getting the object from the `subs` array:

```
// Without `i`
doSomething = (obj, section) => {
    if (
        obj.previousPosition === 'in' &&
        obj.currentPosition === 'below'
    ) {
        // The if is not needed anymore.
        setActiveItem(section);
    }
}
```

This would also remove the need for `subs` in the `doSomething` function.